# Any possible way to align the font by the number of font occurrence?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>aatatgcatgccccagattgcccatgccgata</div>
<div style="left:7%; position:absolute;">cat</div>
<div style="left:13%;position:absolute;">cat</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The text "cat" is present at the position 7 and 13 (from the last pattern). I want to display this using 7% and 13% (length of previous pattern). This is an example of how the desired effect/display would be:

```
aatatgcatgccccagattgcccatgccgata
      cat             cat       
||||||   |||||||||||||
  7%       13%
```

I am using %, but it does not work with that. How could I display it correctly?

Comment: Do you use a fixed-width font ? Fixed-width fonts are like the terminal font. Each character will have the same width. It might help you to solve your problem.
In HTML, you can specify text to be rendered 'as is' using the `<pre></pre>` tags. You could also precise the font by applying some CSS styling.

Comment: Btw, the `<font>` tag is not supported in HTML5, you may want to consider rewriting the code above

Comment: Use a monospace font and offset using ems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into the `ch` unit ([see article about units on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#ch)):

> **ch**
>
> This unit represents the width, or more precisely the advance
>   measure, of the glyph '0' (zero, the Unicode character U+0030) in the
>   element's font.

If you use a monospace font (one in which all characters have the same width), that should do the trick. Something like this:

```
<div>aatatgcatgccccagattgcccatgccgata</div>
<div>
    <span style="padding-left:7ch;">cat</span>
    <span style="padding-left:13ch;">cat</span>
</div>
```

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qz92p4ok/1/

Comment: Thank you for answer and then the useful edit of my question. Thank you

Comment: In mozila firebox it gives exact result. But in the chrome browser it not fit with correctly?

Comment: I am using Chrome and seems to be working fine for me. What issue do you get?

Comment: In chrome i changed the `padding-lefT:8ch` and `14ch` then only it is correctly fit.?

Comment: Could you create a demo on jsfiddle.net so I can see the issue?